# How to delete and copy to folder correctly in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, exception

My co-worker and me got a little IT troll battle and I wanted to make an .exe in C# that copies itself to autostart when launched and then shuts down the PC. I got this to work but after a reboot I get an exception that the file already exists. Now I tried to delete it with `File.Delete(@Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup), fileName));`
but I get another exception System.IO.FileNotFoundException: that says it couldn't find "C:\Windows\system32\Test.exe" (Test.exe is the program) I cant post the full error because its in german so, yea.
Is there a way to just ignore the exception and overwrite it anyways?
Here is my full code:

```
String fileName = String.Concat(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName, ".exe");
String filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, fileName);
File.Delete(@Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup), fileName));
File.Copy(filePath, Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup), fileName));
Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 0");
```

Comment: Why would the full error being in German prevent you from posting it?

Comment: Dunno I can add it if you think it helps

Comment: lol @Maarten, well what you can do is first check for file existence before deleting it.

Comment: Why do you think the exe is in the current directory?

Comment: BTW: Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live. Your code does not fall into that category.

Comment: @Thomas because thats where I copied it to. I tried to let it look understandable

Answer (score 0):

Use the override of File.Copy that takes a third argument for overwrite.

```
File.Copy(filePath, Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup), fileName), true);
```

Comment: That worked I guess. Its in the autostart folder but I cant even run it now. When I open it, literally nothing happens. Do you have an idea?

Comment: If you are overwriting the same file, then you wouldn't have any visible affect. I am guessing that this is a console app. If that were the case, I would personally put everything into a try block and push any exception to the console. (Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); followed by Console.ReadKey(true);)
The latter should pause so you can see what the error is, but nothing would show if there is no error.